# How to cope with pyinstaller and pubsub.core.arg1?

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, pyinstaller

When I try to use pyinstaller to make some python code info a binary. System told me it failed to import modules under pubsub.core.arg1, including arg1.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 36, in walk_packages
  File "<string>", line 20, in walk_packages
  File "pubsub\core\arg1\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Should not import this directly, used by pubsub.core if applicable
11089 WARNING: Hidden import "pubsub.core.topicargspecimpl" not found!
11089 WARNING: Hidden import "pubsub.core.publishermixin" not found!
11099 WARNING: Hidden import "pubsub.core.listenerimpl" not found!
11109 WARNING: Hidden import "pubsub.core.topicmgrimpl" not found!
11109 WARNING: Hidden import "pubsub.core.datamsg" not found!
11109 WARNING: Hidden import "pubsub.core.publisher" not found!
```

I've seen some relevant questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329376/pyinstaller-exe-with-pubsub?rq=1) raised on Stack Overflow and some discussions on GitHub. Seems that the problem may not happen with the latest version of software since the hooks got updated. But, bad luck.  I get this problem.

I've used the pubsub v3

```
from pubsub import setupkwargs
from pubsub import pub
```

Seems that pyinstaller tried to import pubsub.core.arg1 directly while once this happened, the **init** file under arg1 will raise error. Hooks are all fine but it just doesn't work.

Here's some extra information:

- pyinstaller: 3.3-dev
- wxpython: 3.0.4.0->3.0.2.0(sorry about the version)
- python: 2.7.10
- platform: win7

Comment: The latest change removed that complicated import stuff. Can you wait a couple days? I just have to update the wheel and release.

Comment: Woo~That's great! Thanks a lot:-)@Schollii

Comment: The dev release is on pypi if you want to try it @valentin, you will have to do `pip install --pre pypubsub`. If you have issues please post on [pypubsub forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pypubsub).